# Lack of access to XNA ContentManager from another project

Tags: c#, xna

i have a bit complicated problem and cause i'm out of ideas i'm here again.

I work on app to generate shots from any 3d engine and i (unfortunately) suggested XNA to achieve this, as we wanted to made app in c#. I want to send my programming mate a library with XNA code (in form of interface) so he doesnt even have to know how image is generated.

Here is my problem - i cant load models and textures for my scene cause contentmanager is not in library project, although i have no problem with running xna game separately.

So here are my questions:

1. Is is possible to acess/load content so it is usable as/in a library?
2. Are there any libraries to generate 3d scenes (in c#) you can recommend?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to load content in a library project. You can create an instance of `ContentManager` outside of the `Game` class and use it to load your content.

The trick to creating a new Instance of `ContentManager` are the two constructors, both of which accept an instance of `IServiceProvidor` as the first argument. Whatever class you are creating the `ContentManager` in can implement this interface. There is only one method you need to implement from this interface, and that's :

```
public object GetService(Type serviceType)
```

It will be called by the `ContentManager` in order to retrieve an instance of `IGraphicsDeviceService`. You'll need a class that can implement this interface, which is mostly events related to Device creation and destruction. There is one important property that needs to be implemented and that is :

```
public GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice
```

I am going to leave a lot of boilerplate code ouf of this answer because you can find it elsewhere on the internetz. The code below assumes you have initialized the XNA Graphics system and created a `GraphicsDevice` before creating instances of this class

```
public class ImageGenerator : IServiceProvider, IGraphicsDeviceService
{
    public GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice { get; private set; }
    public ContentManager ContentManager { get; private set; }

    public ImageGenerator( GraphicsDevice device )
    {
        this.GraphicsDevice = device;
        this.ContentManager = new ContentManager( this );
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == typeof(IGraphicsDeviceService))
        {
            return this;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceCreated;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceDisposing;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceReset;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceResetting;
}
```

Before going down this route however, I would suggest you investigate subclassing `Game` and allowing the XNA Framework handle the heavy lifting, and you can just worry about rendering a scene and creating the image.

Axiom ( http://www.axiom3d.net ) is a C# engine that is capable of generating 3D scenes to a bitmapped image.

Comment: Hmm that would be great i will definitely check this out, thanks for response and waiting for sample!